# can't find app/design/frontend/base/default/, Am i missign something?

Tags: magento

It's really weird what i am really dealing with here, in all the books that i read about learning and developing themes for Magento it points out to the directroy app/design/frontend/base/default/ and that it should contain three folders **(etc. layout, template)**but when i go and search for it i only come up with  **app/design/frontend/Magento** and the Magento folder is empty,reinstalled Magento many times so i am sure it's a clearn installation, what is going on here, why i can't see those directories?

Answer (score 0):

app/design/frontend/base/default , this path restricted to before and till magento version 1.9.x. You shall be downloading and using magento 2.0. For this you have to download magento version 1.9.x